# How to let a Visual Basic 2015 form app run as console app

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have a VB.net 2015 application that I would also like to be able to run as a command-line application.

I found an [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/stws2269%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on how to do this for visual studio 2010 but I cannot do that in 2015.

I think,  I am able to read command line arguments, it’s just that if do not now on how to let my program decide that if command-line arguments are present that it should not show the main form, but only run a specific function that is dedicated for processing the command-line options.

I think if need to do something to intercept an application start event or so? I do not know how to that.

---

*update i have it working now will post code later,after i have finished some code polishing

Comment: In short, you'll need to launch the process as if it were a console app (Disable application framework in VB if I recall) and then write a `Sub Main()` much like you'd have in C# that either does `Application.EnableVisualStyles` followed by `Application.Run(mainForm)` to launch the winform UI or doesn't in which case you get a console. It's been a while since I've done this, so can't remember if you'd need to explicitly hide the console when showing a form. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb

Comment: The article you posted is still valid - I just tested it.  Why do you say it doesnt work?

Comment: Problem is there is no Main, each button and textbox have their function, but the whole app doesnt have a main function. And when i click codeview, and on top go to (myApp Events) then there is a load in bold but clickingon that doesnt create a load function. (like it would in c#). (asuming load would mean the same here

Comment: @Sam Makin, well i cant create the myApp_Startup  event how did you add it ?

Comment: If you get to the MyApplication class, click the left combo-box, then select '(MyApplication Events)', then in the right combo-box select 'Startup' and it will add the event for you, then just follow the rest or the article.  Alternatively just copy and paste the code they reference.

Comment: Also the Main sub is just an example, this could be _any_ class/sub.

Comment: Well my main vb is called AppMain, and although i added AppMain_Startup in my code its not executed, it is as if i created a general custom method but it is not known to visuals studio 2015 that it should be used as a program startup method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97295/discussion-between-sam-makin-and-user3800527).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in VS2015, use the main forms Load event
By going to the properties area and hit the thunder-lightning  icon.
in my example below i typed MyLoader

In there type a subroutine that you like to use as startup
And at the properties area set Opacity of the form to 0%

The effect of that is that the app will be shown invisible shortly.
As the form has to load otherwise the load event wouldnt trigger either.

```
REM inside your program public class

Declare Function AttachConsole Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwProcessId As Int32) As Boolean
Declare Function AllocConsole Lib "kernel32" () As Int32
Declare Function FreeConsole Lib "kernel32" () As Boolean

Private Sub MyLoader(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim args = My.Application.CommandLineArgs

    If args.Count > 0 Then
        Me.Hide()
        Me.Opacity = 0

        AttachConsole(-1)
        AllocConsole()
        Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf + "Here you can output something")


        If UCase(args(0)) = "HELP" Then Console.WriteLine("no help")


        End If
        Console.Write(vbCrlf + System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory + "\")
        FreeConsole()
        Application.Exit()

    ElseIf args.Count = 0
        Me.Opacity = 1.0

        REM if no argument is clicked start with a default event / method /  or...
        Call Button1_Click(Nothing, Nothing)

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The article is valid and works fine in 2015.

To add the startup event manually go to the MyApplication class, click the left combo-box, then select '(MyApplication Events)', then in the right combo-box select 'Startup' and it will add the event for you, then just follow the rest or the article. Alternatively just copy and paste the code they reference.

Also the Main sub in the article is just an example, this could be any class/sub that you want to run when command line arguments are passed.

Comment: If i go to my application events, there is no such thing as a "Startup" event in my windows form based appplication ?

Comment: Are you looking in ApplicationEvents.vb?  This file is generated when you select Show Application Events in the project properties (under the Application tab).

Comment: I think i just solved it, vs2015 only has a Load Event, which you can then assign to any new method / function, the load event is under the main form event, there doesnt seam to be a general load event.

Answer (score 0):

For our batch apps we just look at the .exe path. If the program is being run from a "batch program" folder, or has a specific naming convention, we just call the batch task from the `Load()` event then End the program. If the program runs from another location we invoke the GUI.

```
   If Application.ExecutablePath.ToLower.Contains("task.exe") Then
        mbBatchTask = True
        DoBatch()
        Application.DoEvents()
        End
    Else
        ' continue loading GUI
    End If
```

Comment: Well, it now works it checks if command line options are given if not it will show the forms version / if command line options are given form is hidden and its commands are executed. My main problem was that under vs2010 i had no Startup event/ but i now managed to do it all in mainform Load event (which still fires despite main form is hidden in command line mode).. i'm polishing code will put my answer here later

Comment: Instead of checking path you could be looking at command line options - point is if it is a batch task do the task then `End` the program before leaving `Load()`

Comment: Yep, i do a Application.Exit that handles the console input.
When i got console output working as well i think i post it here